# Expand and collapse in MVC3 Webgird

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors, asp.net-mvc-4

Can somebody help me in implementing Expand/Collapse functionality?

On clicking the *Expand* button, I need to get related data for that corresponding record and display it as a child row.

```
grid.Column(header: "Expand", 
    format: @<text>
        <a href='#' class="expandable-open-button" rel="1" >&gt;</a> 
        <div class="expandable-child-row"></div> 
     </text>)
```

I am thinking of using jQuery. On click of 'Expand' link can we get the data from the database and set the webgrid html to  element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the "child" element (actually a sibling); and [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to expand the element:

```
// add the click handler
$(".expandable-open-button").on("click", function(e) {

    // prevent the default action on the link
    e.preventDefault();

    // select the details row and toggle its visibility
    $(this).next(".expandable-child-row").slideToggle();
});
```

**Edit** You can pass the item ID by adding it to the markup as a data attribute.

```
format: (item) => @<text><a data-id='@item.ID'>
```

Then retrieve it using `attr` in JQuery:

```
.on("click", function(e) {

    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");   
    alert(id);
... }
```

Comment: Can you please advice me how can I pass item id to this function

Comment: @Naresh probably the best way is to add it to the element as an attribute.